# Explicit construction of polynomial representation of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: algorithms, representation-theory, general-linear-group

In order to understand representations of the general linear group $GL(n,K)$, with $K=\mathbb{R}$ or $K=\mathbb{C}$,
I'm looking for an explicit construction of the polynomial representation matrices
mapping $GL(n,K)$ to $GL(m,K)$.
The paper [Stanley; $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ for combinatorialists, doi:10.1017/CBO9781107325548.009](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/pubs/pubfiles/57.pdf)
gives the following example for the polynomial representation $\phi$
of $GL(2,K)$ with $m=3$

$
\left[\begin{matrix}a_{11} & a_{12}\\a_{21} & a_{22}\end{matrix}\right]
\quad
\xrightarrow{\phi}
\quad
\left[\begin{matrix}a_{11}^{2} & 2 a_{11} a_{12} & a_{12}^{2}\\a_{11} a_{21} & a_{11} a_{22} + a_{12} a_{21} & a_{12} a_{22}\\a_{21}^{2} & 2 a_{21} a_{22} & a_{22}^{2}\end{matrix}\right]
$

Sturmfels "Algorithms in Invariant Theory",
doi:10.1007/978-3-211-77417-5 on page 138 lists the case
for $m=4$

$
\left[\begin{matrix}a_{11} & a_{12}\\a_{21} & a_{22}\end{matrix}\right]
\quad
\xrightarrow{\phi}
\quad
\left[\begin{matrix}a_{11}^{3} & a_{11}^{2} a_{12} & a_{11} a_{12}^{2} & a_{12}^{3}\\3 a_{11}^{2} a_{21} & a_{11}^{2} a_{22} + 2 a_{11} a_{12} a_{21} & 2 a_{11} a_{12} a_{22} + a_{12}^{2} a_{21} & 3 a_{12}^{2} a_{22}\\3 a_{11} a_{21}^{2} & 2 a_{11} a_{21} a_{22} + a_{12} a_{21}^{2} & a_{11} a_{22}^{2} + 2 a_{12} a_{21} a_{22} & 3 a_{12} a_{22}^{2}\\a_{21}^{3} & a_{21}^{2} a_{22} & a_{21} a_{22}^{2} & a_{22}^{3}\end{matrix}\right]
$

I'd be most grateful for pointers to the literature providing
an explicit construction for arbitrary $m$. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what your difficulty is. If $x\mapsto a_{11}x+a_{21}y$ and $y\mapsto a_{21}x+a_{22}y$ where does $x^{r}y^{m-r}$ map to?

Comment: There are in general many polynomial representations $\operatorname{GL}(n) \to \operatorname{GL}(m)$: up to isomorphism (simultaneous conjugation) they are classified by partitions with at most $n$ parts. You can find how to build these matrices explicitly in *Young Tableaux* by Fulton, or by looking up similar material on Schur functors.