# Polynomial representation of $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ into $GL(2,\Bbb R)$.

Tags: representation-theory

Does there exist non-trivial polynomial representation of $GL(2,K)$ into $GL(2,K)$, i.e A homomorpism $\tau : GL(2,K) \rightarrow GL(2,K)$ such that $(\tau(g))_{ij} \in R[c_{11},c_{12},c_{21},c_{22}]$?

[Here they discuss](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4320479/1087759) polynomial representation of $GL(2,K)$ for $m \geq 3$.

Comment: $K = \mathbb{R}$ in the above question. Does this work for any field (especially $char(K) \neq 0$)?

Comment: What is $R[c_{11},c_{12},c_{21},c_{22}]$?

Comment: @DanielTeixeira The ring of polynomials in the entries of the matrices.  If you look at the link in the question, they give the definition, a homomorphism where the entries of the new matrix are polynomial functions of the entries of the starting matrix.

Comment: @DanielTeixeira Formal definition of $c_{ij}$, $c_{ij}$ is a map from $GL(n,K) \rightarrow K$ given by $c_{ij}(g) = (i,j)^{th}$ entry of g ($\in GL(n,K)$). So there are $n^{2}$ such functions for $GL(n,K)$. Algebra generated by {$c_{11},\dotsc,c_{nn}$} can be thought as polynomial algebra in $n^2$ indeterminates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "non-trivial." I assume you mean other than the defining representation $V$, and maybe other than the trivial representation in the usual sense. There are many other polynomial representations we can construct starting from $V$, namely the tensors $V \otimes \det(V)^{\otimes k}$ with any integer power of the determinant $\det(V) = \Lambda^2(V)$. I believe these are all of the irreducible $2$-dimensional polynomial representations. Somewhat surprisingly this includes the dual $V^{\ast}$ as a special case; we have $V^{\ast} \cong V \otimes \det(V)^{-1}$.

There are also reducible $2$-dimensional representations given by taking the direct sum of two $1$-dimensional representations $\det(V)^{\otimes k}$. Together I believe these are all the $2$-dimensional polynomial representations.

Comment: Thank you. Is it not that $det(V)$ is one dimensional representation in the sense; that $det$ is a map $det : GL(n,K) \rightarrow K$. By non-trivial I mean defining isomorphism $\tau : GL(2,K) \rightarrow GL(2,K)$ given by $\tau(g) \mapsto g$.

Comment: @sanket: yes, but $V \otimes \det(V)^{\otimes k}$ is a $2$-dimensional representation. Are you sure you meant an *isomorphism*? That's much more restrictive.

Comment: Yes, it is. I will try few examples of these. Thnxs.